# CodeIgniter Resizing And Cropping With Axis

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, jcrop

I have a image cropper on my project in CodeIgniter, which crops the images like [picresize.com](http://www.picresize.com/) does (I'm using [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)). It works great with vanilla code given below:

```
<?php
$save_to = $this->config->item('images_gallery_thumb_folder').$data['photo_image'];

$targ_w = $this->config->item('gallery_thumb_width');
$targ_h = $this->config->item('gallery_thumb_height');
$src = $this->config->item('images_gallery_folder').$data['photo_image'];

$types = array(1 => 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png');
list($width,$height,$type) = getimagesize($src);

switch ($types[$type]) {
    case 'jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        break;
    case 'gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
        break;

    case 'png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
        break;

    default:
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        break;
}

$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($targ_w,$targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);


switch ($types[$type]) {
    case 'jpeg':
        imagejpeg($dst_r, $save_to, 90); //90 = jpeg quality
        break;
    case 'gif':
        imagegif($dst_r, $save_to);
        break;
    case 'png':
        imagepng($dst_r, $save_to);
        break;
    default:
        imagejpeg($dst_r, $save_to, 90); //90 = jpeg quality
        break;
}


imagedestroy($dst_r);
?>
```

But I wanna do this the CodeIgniter way.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
<?php
$img_config = array(
    'source_image'      => $src,
    'new_image'         => $save_to,
    'maintain_ratio'    => false,
    'width'             => $targ_w,
    'height'            => $targ_h,
    'x_axis'            => $_POST['x'],
    'y_axis'            => $_POST['y']
);

$this->load->library('image_lib',$img_config);
//$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->crop();
?>
```

The thing is, it crops from positions, but it does not resize (think like I've set a bigger crop square). It only crops from given position.

I'm also using [image_moo](http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/) library on the project, but I couldn't also succeed with it.

**Edit:**
In Image_moo, here is the code what I've come up with so far:

```
$this->image_moo
                ->load($src)
                ->crop($_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],($_POST['x']+$_POST['w']),($_POST['y']+$_POST['h']))
                ->resize($targ_w,$targ_h)
                ->save($save_to,true);
```

The thing is that, it when I use resize parameter, it ignores the crop line altogether and resizes the whole image. If I resize before and call crop later, it just fails.
I can overcome it with using two image_moo calling, which I would not prefer.

This does not work either:

```
$this->image_moo
                ->load($src)
                ->crop($_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],($_POST['x']+$_POST['w']),($_POST['y']+$_POST['h']))
                //->resize($targ_w,$targ_h)
                ->save($save_to,true)
                ->resize($targ_w,$targ_h)
                ->save($save_to,true);
```

E.g: this way it works:

```
$this->image_moo
                ->load($src)
                ->crop($_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],($_POST['x']+$_POST['w']),($_POST['y']+$_POST['h']))
                //->resize($targ_w,$targ_h)
                ->save($save_to,true);
            $this->image_moo
                ->load($save_to)
                ->resize($targ_w,$targ_h)
                ->save($save_to,true);
```

So how do I resize+crop with given x/y offsets with CodeIgniter (or image_moo) way with one calling of image_moo or CI image_lib?

You should be probably asking why I'm concerned calling it twice. Well, the PQ is important, and I'm concerned because calling it twice will reduce the image quality.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You would have to do a crop first, to get the correct ratio, and then do a resize. In Codeigniter they are split into separate functions.

Comment: is your crop script works......

Comment: @Jeemusu - the thing is that I couldn't manage it. Should I make a bigger thumbnail first, then resize it to desired width/height you mean ? Can you please be more specific ?

Comment: @AnkurSaxena - Its working itself, but it is not enough. Not every PHP installations have GD2 etc (I'm not gonna have management rights to the server which this script is gonna be on, so.). CodeIgniter manages it all at the background. That is one of the reasons I want it the CI way. Plus having everything CI way in a CI script is better if you'd ask me.

Comment: sorry my friend don't mind.i also work on image processing through gd lib.i don't have  crop code.

Comment: Apologies @Arda, I completely missed the fact that you had mentioned Image_Moo. See http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/161469/P90 which may be of some use to you.

Comment: @Gavin , no worries. I know the page, and have the exact same issue with this guy: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/161469/P60/#941228

Comment: @Arda, odd, I have used image_moo with jcrop before and with great success however I cannot access the code anymore as it is hosted on a clients server. If I come across anything I'll update you.

Comment: Thanks @Gavin, I'm also playing with the code. Hope it succeeds

Comment: @Gavin , please check my question for example code edits: I'v succeeded, but with calling image_moo twice (also provided the reason). Did you manage it with only calling image_moo once?

Comment: @Arda, I'm pretty sure I managed to do it in one call, but can't be 100% sure. If it works in 2 calls, I suppose it's better than nothing ;)

Comment: @Arda, when you say image_moo doesn't work, is it giving you an error? Are you displaying errors, something like this: `if ($this->image_moo->error) print $this->image_moo->display_errors();`

Comment: @Jeemusu - Please check my recent edits. Now it works, but with calling two calls. That is my issue.

Comment: @Arda I see, with image_moo, aren't you supposed to use resize_crop() to do a resize and a crop, rather than calling the two methods at once.

Comment: @Jeemusu resize_crop first resizes, then crops. So the result is not what I needed. I need the opposite, something like crop_resize :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your given Codeigniter code is OK except for one piece of logic: You're operating on and outputting to the same image file twice, so your output file gets overwritten by the last change to the original file.

I believe this is a limitation of CI's Image_Lib class, as each operation is done separately - there is no way to "resize and crop" in one go.

You have to reinitialize the Image_Lib class between each action to make sure the next action gets called on the output file of the last operation.

```
$img_config = array(
    'source_image'      => $src,
    'new_image'         => $save_to,
    'maintain_ratio'    => false,
    'width'             => $targ_w,
    'height'            => $targ_h,
    'x_axis'            => $_POST['x'],
    'y_axis'            => $_POST['y']
);

$this->load->library('image_lib', $img_config);
$this->image_lib->resize();

// Now change the input file to the one that just got resized
// See also $this->image_lib->clear()
$img_config['source_image'] = $save_to;
$this->image_lib->initialize($img_config); 

$this->image_lib->crop();
```

You could also use two different config arrays:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

$this->image_lib->initialize(array(
    'source_image'      => $src,
    'new_image'         => $save_to,
    'maintain_ratio'    => false,
    'width'             => $targ_w,
    'height'            => $targ_h,
));
$this->image_lib->resize();

$this->image_lib->clear();

$this->image_lib->initialize(array(
    'source_image'      => $save_to,
    'x_axis'            => $_POST['x'],
    'y_axis'            => $_POST['y']
));
$this->image_lib->crop();
```

Alternatively, you could [create the copy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) of the image file first and then operate on that in each call to the image lib class, saving you the hassle of reinitializing with a new `source_image`:

```
copy($src, $save_to);
$this->load->library('image_lib', array(
    'source_image'      => $save_to,
    'maintain_ratio'    => false,
    'width'             => $targ_w,
    'height'            => $targ_h,
    'x_axis'            => $_POST['x'],
    'y_axis'            => $_POST['y']
));
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->crop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I try to avoid calling the library twice. Your answer is the exact thing I do with image_moo. That is the first place I've asked the question. Are you sure this can't be done with one calling both with CI's image_lib and matmoo.com's image_moo ?

Comment: There's definitely no way to do it in one go with CI's Image_lib. Have you tried the `resize_crop` method in Image_Moo? One point of the CI library is to abstract some of the functionality so it can work with GD/GD2, NetPBM, or ImageMagick if you choose. Image_Moo uses only GD as your original code does, you might just want to make your own function with the vanilla PHP code you seem to be happy with and extend CI's Image_lib. Still, I'm surprised you're noticing reduced image quality just by calling crop/resize separately.

Comment: Image_moo's resize_crop first resizes the whole image, then crops. So it's not the thing I exactly want. If I used that, I need to recalculate resized image's dimensions, positions and width/height to make the crop. I need something like opposite, like crop_resize :)

Comment: Ah I see. The "vanilla" code you're using is short and sweet, and seems to do what you want. Why not just extend the Image_lib class and tack it on as a new method?

Comment: Well the thing is that I'm concerned it won't / may not be working online. I won't be able to manage the server that the code will be uploaded (maybe GD or GD2 won't be installed, so I need to rewrite that code again), so even if I've extended the image_lib with the vanilla code my concerns would still go on. Anyways, you clarified me a lot, so I'm marking your answer as accepted, thanks!

Comment: I will say that it's unlikely GD or GD2 won't be installed. If it is an isue, you can just check if it's available in your function and use another method if it is not (just fall back to Image_lib's the regular crop/resize methods).

Comment: If a particular image library isn't installed, surely image_lib is your best bet as you can switch between different libraries while still calling the same functions.